# Query data with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I query three times to reach out what I need, but I believe there might be a better/smarter way of doing it.

```
ObservableCollection<ReadingEquipmentViewModel> AllCourses;

var allCourses = AllCourses.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < allCourses.Count; i++)
{
     if (allCourses[i].ClassType == CourseType.IsScience)
     {
        var EnrollmentList = allCourses[i].Enrollments.ToList()
                                          .Where(x=>x.IsDone || x.IsProgress).ToList();
     }
}
```

Comment: if those are `IQueryable`, avoid calling `ToList` on them.

Comment: @DanielA.White I do not see `ToString()` in my implementation

Comment: i meant `ToList`.

Comment: @DanielA.White Then I need to know how to handle without reach out to List. any suggestion or guidance?

Comment: You are calling `ToList` twice. First call is useless

Comment: Can I write all this code in one `linq` query?

Comment: What do you plan on doing with `EnrollmentList`?

Comment: @GiladGreen it will be used for other method that I will be calling.

Comment: and what do you want from the original object? Do you need the other properties or only that?

Comment: only that. I do not need any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can use `Where` to filter only those items where `ClassType == CourseType.IsScience`. Then you can use `Select` to retrieve for each of those items only the `Enrollments` that are `Done` or `InProgress`:

```
var result = AllCourses.Where(c => c.ClassType == CourseType.IsScience)
                       .Select(c => new { 
                           Course = c, 
                           EnrollmentList = c.Enrollments.Where(x=>x.IsDone || x.IsProgress)
                        });
```

If all you need for each item is the items that first for the inner where then:

```
var result = AllCourses.Where(c => c.ClassType == CourseType.IsScience)
                       .Select(c => c. Enrollments.Where(x=>x.IsDone || x.IsProgress));
```

*As a side note, about all the `ToList` - there is no need to call the `ToList` unless you want to materialize the items in the query.*

---

As suggested by @NetMage in the comments, if you do not need the separation between the different courses and just want a flat list of the `EnrollmentList` then use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`:

```
var result = AllCourses.Where(c => c.ClassType == CourseType.IsScience)
                       .SelectMany(c => c. Enrollments.Where(x=>x.IsDone || x.IsProgress));
```

Comment: Perhaps a `SelectMany` would be better in your second query?

Comment: @NetMage - hm... might be.. Will add about it. The reason I didn't write before is that OP might want to keep separation between the different courses.

Comment: `SelectMange` ? LOL

Answer (score 1):

try something along these lines...

```
var query = from course in allCourses
            from enrollment in course.Enrollments
            where course.ClassType == CourseType.IsScience
                && (enrollment.IsDone
                || enrollment.IsProgress)
            select enrollment;
var enrollments = query.ToList();
```

**Note:** take good care of the `.ToList` as when dealing with an IQueryable behind the scenes, calling `.ToList` too early (as in before where clauses) could have a dramatic performance penalty on your code